# prove that a subcomplex of a cell complex is a cell complex in its own right

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here is the definition, quoted from Hatcher‘s algebraic topology:

[image]

[image]

Hatcher states that

> A subcomplex of a cell complex $X$ is a closed subspace $A ⊂ X$ that is a union of cells of $X$. Since $A$ is closed, the characteristic map of each cell in $A$ has image contained in $A$, and in particular the image of the attaching map of each cell in $A$ is contained in $A$, so $A$ is a cell complex in its own right.

I can figure out that since $A$ is closed, and for continuous map $D_{\alpha}^n$ we have $D_{\alpha}^n(\overline{e_{\alpha}^n}) = \overline{D_{\alpha}^n(e_{\alpha}^n)}$ hence contained in $A$. But I still got no idea how it's a cell complex in its own right. It still not matches the definition described above. How to decompose $A$ to n-skeleton inductively?

Comment: The $n$th skeleton of $A$ simply consists in the intersection of $A$ and the $n$th skeleton of $X$.

Comment: @arnett thanks. I got some maybe more detailed explanations than hatcher’s in Lee’s Introduction to topological manifolds